# How to send files from mac to iPhone's "On my iPhone" folder via USB?

Tags: iphone, ios

I can send files from my mac to the iPhone "on my iPhone" folder through airport, but since it's a bit slow, I was wondering if it was possible to do it through the USB cable.
I can open Finder from mac, go to the Files tab and drag some files, but I'm forced to drag the file into a specific application, while I want to copy the file to the "On my iPhone" folder instead.

Edit:
I'm on mac osx 12.1.
Here's the screenshot of the Finder window I can use to send files (though I'm forced to send files in a specific application folder, instead of able to send it to the root folder).

[image]